# store session in memcache Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, memcached

Hello i have a CircularReferenceException for monolog.processor  when i try to launch my app. 
services.yml

```
      selfcare_memcache:
      class: Selfcare\Bundle\FrontBundle\Services\Lib\SelfcareMemcache
      arguments: [%host%,%serveurMemcache_port%,'@logger'] 

      selfcare_session_memcache:
         class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
    arguments: ['@selfcare_memcache']
```

config.yml:

```
    framework:
    session:
        handler_id: selfcare_session_memcache
```

I don't know how to deal with this kind of exception, do you additional informations ?